# Show $\int_o^\infty \frac{|sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du$ Convergence for $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis

Show $\int_o^\infty \frac{|sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du$ Convergence for $a>0$.

and show that for all $h\in R$:
$$\int_o^\infty \frac{|sin(\frac{hs}{2})|}{|h|^a(a+s^{a+1})}ds\le\int_o^\infty \frac{|sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du$$

I know to show $\int_b^\infty \frac{|sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du$ Convergence for any $b>0$. but how to show $\int_0^b \frac{|sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du$ Convergence?

Comment: Please include relevant context. For instance, your attempts. Anyway, this is easily solved by integration by parts. $|\sin u|$ has mean value $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio

How integration by parts is done with the absolute sigh?

Comment: The same way it is done without.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio 
relevant context has been added :)

Comment: Is it actually true?

Comment: Is this true? Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}=\infty$?

Comment: this is what i'm trying to find out. it is a question from test, and it says "show".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du=\int_0^1 \frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du+\int_1^\infty \frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du$$

converges for $a\in(0,1)$.

Indeed

$$\int_0^1 \frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du$$

converges for $a\in(0,1)$ and diverges for $a\ge1$ for comparison test with $\frac{1}{u^{a}}$ since

$$u\to0 \quad \frac{\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}}{\frac{1}{u^a}}=\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u}\to1$$

And

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du$$

converges for $a> 0$ since

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}du<\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{u^{1+a}}du$$

Comment: Can you please explain this:
"and diverges for $a\ge1$ for comparison test with $\frac{1}{u^{a}}$."
$$\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}} \le \frac{1}{u^a}$$ and from that I don't know to conclude diverge from comparison test

Comment: I mean $$\frac{\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}}{\frac{1}{u^a}}\to1$$

Comment: @Y.ofir In other words let consider that for $u\to0$ $\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u^{1+a}}\sim \frac{1}{u^a}$